# how do I override spree override expired_reimbursement_type and default_reimbursement_type

Tags: spree

On Spree 2.4, I can't seem to find a good way to override expired_reimbursement_type and/or default_reimbursement_type in my app.

I tried this

```
Spree::Reimbursement::ReimbursementTypeEngine.class_eval do
  self.refund_time_constraint = 90.days
  self.default_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::OriginalPayment
  self.exchange_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::StoreCredit
end
```

And also in initializer/spree.rb

```
Spree::Reimbursement::ReimbursementTypeEngine.refund_time_constraint = 90.days
Spree::Reimbursement::ReimbursementTypeEngine.default_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::OriginalPayment
Spree::Reimbursement::ReimbursementTypeEngine.exchange_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::StoreCredit
```

but neither seemed to work correctly

Comment: Nevermind, the first example works correctly

Answer (score 1):

this works correctly

```
Spree::Reimbursement::ReimbursementTypeEngine.class_eval do
  self.refund_time_constraint = 90.days
  self.default_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::OriginalPayment
  self.expired_reimbursement_type = Spree::ReimbursementType::StoreCredit
end
```